# Eslint warning about deconstruction

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How would I use array destructuring on this. I'm getting a linter waring.

`Use array destructuring. [prefer-destructuring]`

```
const block = Object.entries(products).reduce((acc, item) => {
      acc[item[0]] = item[1];
      return acc;
    }, {}
```

);

Comment: Did you read the rule? https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-destructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destructure `item` in the parameter list into `[key, val]`:

```
const block = Object.entries(products).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  acc[key] = val;
  return acc;
}, {});
```